# getElementById on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic element which changes its `id` on click. After its clicked it also runs a function, which uses `getElementById` to select itself, because the `id` it selects is the one assigned to the element on click. When I try to assign this element to a variable, it's assigned `null`. I read somewhere that this can happen with dynamically created elements, but couldn't find a solution. Here's the relevant code:

```
function renderPlayerHand() {
    player.hand.forEach(function (element, index) {
        var card = document.createElement("span");
        card.classList.add("face_up_card");
        switch(element[1]) {
            case 'Spade':
                card.classList.add("spade")
                break;
            case 'Diamonds':
                card.classList.add("diamonds")
                break;
            case 'Clubs':
                card.classList.add("clubs")
                break;
            case 'Hearts':                    
                card.classList.add("hearts")
                break;
        }
        card.id = `p${index + 1}c`;
        card.innerHTML = element[0] + "<br />" + element[1];
        card.setAttribute("onclick","startTurn();this.id='a1c'");
        document.body.appendChild(card);
    });
}

function startTurn() {
    console.log("Turn Started");
    var firstCard = document.getElementById('a1c');
    console.log(firstCard);
}
```

Comment: `startTurn();this.id='a1c'`  exactly what order did you expect these two statements to execute in? Also, why not just pass `this` into `startTurn` so you don't need to query for the element?

Comment: You realise that this code will produce multiple elements with the same `id` if you click more than one card. What's the reasoning behind changing the `id` anyway? It just doesn't make any sense

Comment: Using `id`'s in the first place is generally not a good idea. They're easy enough to understand, which is why so many newbies use them, but it doesn't take long before managing them becomes a problem (as you are experiencing). And, changing an element's `id`? That's just not a good approach to any problem.

Comment: Shoot I didn't think about that, I was planning on adding a `firstCard.removeAttribute("onclick");` so that the card cannot be clicked anymore, but that doesn't do anything to prevent other cards from being clicked on. 

If not using `id`s, what should I try to do? The code is part of a card game, and the `id` moves the card from your hand to the board. The `a1c` represents the first slot on the board.

Comment: There are a number of ways to reference elements (by class, by hierarchical position in the document as a whole, by position relative to other elements). You also shouldn't be using `onclick` (event properties), you should hook up your events using `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: I've actually tried using `.addEventListener()`, but for some reason the function inside will execute on load and not `onclick` or `ondblclick`.

Comment: @Hihikokun I bet you had `addEventListener('click', functioName())` where you actually want `addEventListener('click', functionName)` (no `()`)

Comment: @Phil That worked thank you. I also want to ask about your first suggestion of passing `this` into `startTurn`. I tried putting `this.id='a1c';` at the start of the function but that doesn't seem to work. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: My suggestion is exactly the same as the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you claim the id as `'a1c'` after you call `startTurn()`. In the following, the id is claimed inside the function.

```js
function renderPlayerHand() {
  player.hand.forEach(function(element, index) {
    var card = document.createElement("span");
    card.classList.add("face_up_card");
    switch (element[1]) {
      case 'Spade':
        card.classList.add("spade")
        break;
      case 'Diamonds':
        card.classList.add("diamonds")
        break;
      case 'Clubs':
        card.classList.add("clubs")
        break;
      case 'Hearts':
        card.classList.add("hearts")
        break;
    }
    card.id = `p${index + 1}c`;
    card.innerHTML = element[0] + "<br />" + element[1];
    card.setAttribute("onclick", "startTurn(this)");
    document.body.appendChild(card);
  });
}
function startTurn(el) {
  el.id = 'a1c';
  console.log("Turn Started");
  var firstCard = el;
  console.log(firstCard);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did fix my issue, although from the comments I'm getting I might have to scrap this method completely! At least now I know to pay attention to order, ty.